# Comparison between regression of $a = bc^t$ and $\log a = \log b +t \log c$

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, estimation, data-transformation

This question is more qualitative then about the maths behind the equation.

Variables:
a = month (1, 2, 3, )
t = shipments of a product in that month
You wish to derive the relationship between $a$ and $t$ via regression.

(Note: i am not running a specific regression. this is a theoretical question)

**Case I: Linear Regression**
You regress $a$ on $t$ in a simple linear regression and get a regression equation as below:
$a = b  + ct  $
Your co-efficients will be $b$: intercept and $c$: slope
You can then get $p$-values, confidence intervals, etc for the equation

**Case II: Exponential Regression**
If the relationship between $a$ and $t$ is exponential form, you regress:
$a = bc^t$ and get an equation in that form.

**Case III:**
You take logs of both sides of $a = bc^t$ to get $\log a = \log b + t\log c$ (thanks for the correction, my logs is a bit rusty).
Specifically, if you have 100 data-value pairs, you take their logs. Then, you run a linear regression on the log-transformed values. Once you get the regression equation, take anti-log to transform it back into an exponential equation.

My understanding is that:
Given that the underlying relationship between $a$ and $t$ is exponential, Case I will not be appropriate.

> My question is:
>   A. Out of Cases II and III, which would be appropriate.
>   B. What would be the difference between the two
>   C. Will there anything "lost" in the transformation

I hope the question is clearer now.